# Create an event in google calendar from google spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script

I create a google time off form that sends information to a spreadsheet. From the spreadsheet I would like it to create an event in a specific calendar. I have not been able to test because it gives an error message when the start and end date are the same (employee asks for one day off) I get an error message. The code I used is below.

```
function createCalendarEvent() {
 let timeoffcalendar= CalendarApp.getCalendarById("mycalendaridisenteredhere");
 let sheet= SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();

 let schedule= sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
 schedule.splice (0,1);

 schedule.forEach(function(entry) {
 timeoffcalendar.createAllDayEvent(entry[1],entry[2],entry[3]);
 });
}
```

Error message is "Exception: Event start date must be before event end date" Any suggestions would be helpful. entry 1 is employee name, entry 2 is start date, entry 3 end date

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Please provide some sample data.

Comment: The exception seem straight forward what's the problem?

Answer (score 1):

#### Start date must be before end date

Evidently it cannot be the same date

```
function createCalendarEvent() {
  const cal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById("calid");
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet0');
  let vs = sh.getDataRange().getValues();
  vs.splice(0, 1);
  vs.forEach(r => {
    cal.createAllDayEvent(r[0], r[1], r[2]);
    //cal.createAllDayEvent(r[3], r[5], r[6]);

  });
}
```

| COL1 | COL2 | COL3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Event1 | 5/18/2022 | 5/19/2022 |
| Event2 | 5/19/2022 | 5/20/2022 |
| Event3 | 5/20/2022 | 5/21/2022 |

Comment: I changed my code to the code posted but not it is not creating an event in the calendar. It says the execution started/execution complete, but no event is created in the corresponding calendar. For reference the spreadsheet has the following column headers: timestamp| email address| todays date| name| request date| beginning on| ending on|. This information is pulled from a form that was created.

Comment: Which colums are Title,StartDate,EndDate?

Comment: Column D title (name), column F (startDate), column G (endDate)